# Are there finitely many pairs of integers that are divisible by the same primes such that adding $1$ also keeps them divisible by the same primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Integers *m* and *n* have the same prime divisors but *m* is not equal to *n*, i.e. the same primes are just raised by different powers, resulting in integers *m* and *n*. But we also know that *m+1* and *n+1* have also the same prime divisors.

Are there finitely or infinitely many such integer pairs (m,n)?

Comment: With $m=2$ and $n=4$, both are divisible by $2$, by $m+1=3$ and $n+1=5$ do not have the same prime divisors (they are both primes). Your question might be ill-posed.

Comment: Are you specifically asking if there are infinitely many $p$ such that $\gcd(p^a + 1, p^b + 1) \ne 1, a \ne b$?

Comment: I believe the question is are there an infinite number of $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ where $m=\prod\limits_{k=1}^K p_k^{\ i_k}$, $n=\prod\limits_{k=1}^K p_k^{\ j_k}$, $m+1=\prod\limits_{r=1}^R q_r^{\ s_r}$, and $n+1=\prod\limits_{r=1}^R q_r^{\ t_r}$ assuming $p_k,q_r\in\mathbb{P}$ and $i_k,j_k,s_r,t_r\in\mathbb{Z}^+$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are infinitely many pairs. Any pair of the form $(2^n - 2, 2^n(2^n - 2))$ works for $n$ at least $2$, since $2^n(2^n - 2) + 1 = (2^n - 1)^2$.